# Wordpress Genesis – Create two menu locations in header (primary + secondary)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, genesis

I’m pretty new to the Genesis Framework and I wonder if it is possible to create two menu location in the header?
It should look like this:

Primary Menu ——– (Logo) ——— Secondary Menu

The primary menu should align to the left and the secondary menu should align to the right.
My thoughts were just to add two menu locations to my childtheme, “header right” and “header left” and assign the menus to them.
I’m new to the filter and hooks but as far as I know this shouldn’t be that much trouble. Or am I wrong?
Any help would be appreciated! I’m looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

This code goes in the child themes function.php file:

```
?php
//do not copy the opening php tag above

/**
 * Swap Primary Nav to Header Right and Remove Wrap
 * 
 * @package Swap Primary Nav
 * @author Neil Gee
 * @link http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/switching-primary-menu-genesis-theme-header-right/
 * @copyright (c) 2014, Neil Gee
 */
 remove_action( 'genesis_after_header','genesis_do_nav' ) ;
 add_action( 'genesis_header_right','genesis_do_nav' );
 add_theme_support( 'genesis-structural-wraps', array( 'header', 'menu-secondary', 'footer-widgets', 'footer' ) );//menu-primary is removed
```

You can actually just add the remove_action and add_action functions at the beginning of the code and that alone will reposition the menu. The remove_action moves the menu away completely and the add_action adds it to the new location.